# Overriding default picture conversions in Nuxeo

Tags: nuxeo

I am trying to override default picture converter in Nuxeo.

By default, Nuxeo provides following OOTB converters

- Thumbnail
- Small
- Medium
- Large
- Orignal

I want to reduce the converters to

- Thumbnail
- Orignal

Following are the configurations that I have tried

1. Created a Multi-Module Contribution using Nuxeo-cli utility

   Steps followed to create contribution

   ```bash
   $>nuxeo bootstrap multi-module
   ```

   ```bash
   $>nuxeo bootstrap contribution
   ```

   target component used for contribution is `org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.picture.ImagingComponent`

   ```bash
   $>nuxeo bootstrap package
   ```
2. Added following extension to the OSGI-INF/picture-conversion-core-contrib.xml file [Ref](https://explorer.nuxeo.com/nuxeo/site/distribution/Nuxeo%20Platform%20LTS%202019-10.10/viewContribution/org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.picture.ImagingComponent.default.config--pictureConversions/override)

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <component name="org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.picture.ImagingComponent.default.config.override">
   <require>
       org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.picture.ImagingComponent.default.config
   </require>
       <extension target="org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.picture.ImagingComponent" point="pictureConversions">
           <pictureConversion chainId="Image.Blob.Resize" description="Thumbnail size" id="Thumbnail" maxSize="100" order="0" rendition="true"/>
           <pictureConversion chainId="Image.Blob.Resize" description="Original jpeg image" id="OriginalJpeg" order="100" rendition="true"/>
       </extension>
   </component>
   ```

   I want to keep only two picture conversions hence adding only *Thumbnail* converter and *OriginalJpeg* converter.
3. After creating package I am installing the package on Nuxeo server with following command.

   ```bash
   $>nuxeoctl mp-install  /path/to/dir/sample_picture_converter-package-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
   ```

Even though the component is installed correctly on the Nuxeo server, the server is converting the images with default formats(ie. Thumbnail, Small, Medium, Large and Original).

What are the steps to override a default contribution in Nuxeo without Nuxeo studio?

[Cross Posted](https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/44d1d31b442a4a9988213d17936a8d19/Overriding-default-picture-conve) on Nuxeo forum

Comment: Cross Posted the same on Nuxeo Forum: [link](https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/44d1d31b442a4a9988213d17936a8d19/Overriding-default-picture-conve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to disable the default picture conversions explicitly in OSGI-INF/picture-conversion-core-contrib.xml. Given below the updated OSGI configuration.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<component name="org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.picture.ImagingComponent.default.config.override">

    <require>
        org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.picture.ImagingComponent.default.config
    </require>

    <extension target="org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.picture.ImagingComponent" point="pictureConversions">
        <pictureConversion chainId="Image.Blob.Resize" description="Thumbnail size" id="Thumbnail" maxSize="100" order="0" rendition="true"/>
        <pictureConversion chainId="Image.Blob.Resize" description="Original jpeg image" id="OriginalJpeg" order="100" rendition="true"/>
        <pictureConversion chainId="Image.Blob.Resize" id="Small" enabled="false" />
        <pictureConversion chainId="Image.Blob.Resize" id="Medium" enabled="false" />
        <pictureConversion chainId="Image.Blob.Resize" id="FullHD" enabled="false" />
    </extension>
</component>
```

Answered by [LaraGranite](https://answers.nuxeo.com/users/0f962e46-2c0c-4854-8237-2ca03c88bed9) on [Nuxeo forum](https://app.quandora.com/object/79ca4834-22a3-4330-b291-00ef6e2b1fc5)